# How to produce uniformly distributed low-frequency noise?

Tags: matlab, filter-design, noise

I want to design noise for the sake of modulation and it should have a frequency of under 1 Hz. This seems impossible to do for a frequency that low.

Here is my Matlab script. The lowest frequency that gives me something useful is 2 Hz. But also then the noise does not travel over the whole amplitude range from 0 to 1. It jumps to 0.9 and is stuck there.

Is there maybe a filter that is suited better?

```
fs = 44100;
L = 10 * fs;
fpass = 2;
fstop = fpass*2;
x = rand(L,1);

fs = 44100;
Wp = fpass * (2 * pi)/fs;
Ws = fstop * (2 * pi)/fs;
Rp = 0.01;
Rs = 40;

[n, ~] = ellipord(Wp, Ws, Rp, Rs);
[b, a] = ellip(n, Rp, Rs, Wp);


y = filter(b, a, x);

plot(x) 
hold on;
plot(y)
hold off;
```

[image]

Comment: Please clarify: do you need uniformly distributed noise bandlimited to 1Hz within a 22.05 kHz band?

Comment: I need uniformly distributed noise for an audio application. This is supposed to modulate a signal with 44,1 kHz sampling rate. It actually says 0.15 Hz noise in the paper, but I guess that is impossible with this method

Comment: Yeah, it'll be difficult, not least because any filtering will introduce correlation between the samples and is likely to affect the uniformity. BTW, I haven't heard of noise modulating a signal. However, it's not unusual to add a random phase variation to the modulating carrier. That's a different but much more feasible problem.

Comment: Your filter design is prone to numerical error: you are using a sampling frequency of 44.1 kHz and a corner frequency of 2 Hz (stopband 4 Hz). The poles are, virtually, at the origin.

Comment: @MBaz It is for an audio application it should emulate random variations. Hmm, random phase variations. Why would anyone want that in communcation systems? Maybe this could be a solution for my problem

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I know, this is the lowest it gets. I just don't know a better way to generate a smooth noise with a low frequency. I could just call rand() less often, but then it will not be as smooth

Comment: @neolith Have you tried brute-force downsampling?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Not yet, because I figured it would not sound very natural. I might give it a try though. Ugly solutions are accepted as long as they sound well

Comment: Instead of downsampling, I'd try upsampling: start with a sampling frequency of 2 Hz and then get to 44.1k  (by doing a few rounds of resample). Then verify the noise still has the statistical properties you need.

Comment: Nobody wants random carrier phase variations :-)  The problem, is, they happen in actual hardware, so one one wants to simulate them.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is one way you could do it: with LTspice, use the `white()` function. There are also `rand()` ([0,1] V, pulses) and `random()` ([0,1] V, smooth pulses), but `white(2*fs*time)` will give you what you want between [-0.5, 0.5] V:

[image: white()]

`B1` is a behavioural current source (`bi`, or `bi2`, as it appears in the component selection dialog, <kbd>F2</kbd>), and the `.wave`command exports it as a `.wav` file named `output.wav`, with 16 bits resolution (can be anything from 1 to 32) and 44.1 kHz sampling frequency (can be any number from 1 to 4294967295). For this case, the file is 8,820,046 bytes, which can be imported. This is a 2 Hz white noise, band limited, properly sampled signal, 100 sec long. Optional settings can include a tighter timestep, though `opt plotwinsize=0`, here, disables waveform compression and for a 2 Hz signal, it may not make much sense.

Comment: Sounds like worth a try. Will waste a bit of memory on the DSP though. Will keep the question open a little bit longer to gather more ideas

Comment: You are not restricted to those numbers, you can simulate for as many seconds you like (the `.tran` command).

Comment: Yeah have to see. I am not really experienced in LTSpice. Could never bother because of the horrible interface.

Comment: @neolith Judging a book by the cover is not such a good idea. I should know, I have been using LTspice since a lot of time back. If you need help, just post a comment, I can help.

Comment: I know it is a big thing. It has models for almost every real part. Maybe this is a good reason to get into it